# How to make Sublime Text3 connect with MAMP

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

I want to upload a genesis zip file to my local Wordpress in MAMP using ftp with Sublime Text3 but can´t make both connect.

I am using:

```
host: localhost
user: root
password: root
port: 3306 or 22
remote_path: /home/..., /Aplicaciones/MAMP/htdocs
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have researched everywhere and can't find more information about this.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to FTP to a local MAMP / WAMP install?  No need, just dump your files into the htdocs root folder and done.  In sublime or dreamweaver just set the webroot to the htdocs path and you are done.  any new file you create will "be uploaded" although, its not uploading anywhere since it is local.

Comment: Hello Stephen: Is the webroot the same as the remote_path? I am new in this and still confused with some names.